# Speed up loops to assign values from several data frames

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop, assign

I created loops to assign column values from a `data.frame` to a column of another `data.frame` based on some conditions:

```
for ( lineTab1 in 1 : dim(tab1)[1] ) {
  for ( lineTab2 in 1 : dim(tab2)[1] ) {
    if ( tab1$id[lineTab1] == tab2$id[lineTab2]) & 
     tab1$year[lineTab1] == tab2$year[lineTab2]) ) {
  tab1$region[lineTab1] <- tab2$region[lineTab2]) }
}
}
```

My loops are too slow! The first `data.frame` (`tab1`) has 60,000,000 observations and the second `data.frame` (`tab2`) has 1000 observations. Is there a way to speed up these loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a merge.  There's a `merge` function in base R that will probably do what you need without difficulty.

Note that I'm assuming that `tab2` is just a lookup table for id/year region.  If there are other columns in `tab2`, then you can either use the `data.table` solution below, or remove the remaining columns from `tab2`

In base R, you can expect this merge to take ~3 minutes, based on some experimentation.

Using the library `dplyr`, this reduces to about 5 seconds, as `left_join(tab1, tab2)`.

Using the library `data.table`, this takes only about a second, although the setup time is a little higher:

```
setDT(tab1)
setDT(tab2)
system.time(tab1[tab2, region := i.region, on=c("id","year")])
```

For timing data I used sample data generated as

```
tab2 <- expand.grid(id=1:10, year=2000:2010)
tab2$region <- rnorm(110)
tab1 <- data.frame(id=sample(1:10, 6e7, replace=T), year=sample(2000:2010, 6e7, replace=T))
```

Comment: ....although with 60million records maybe **data.table** or **dplyr** would be preferable.

Comment: Hey I updated the code for your `data.table` solution to reflect more common usage. I did not update your timing. In particular note that OP does _not_ seem to be requiring a full merge, so these codes are likely to be much slower if there are other columns, especially in `tab2`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm not as familiar with `data.table` as with `dplyr`, but your edit had `i.region`, which gave me an error.  Is there something I'm missing, or was that just a typo

Comment: You must be using an old version of `data.table`; `i.region` makes sure we refer to the column `region` in `tab2` (in case there was another column named `region` in `tab1`, i.e., the `i.` approach is more robust). As far as I know, this behavior is current with the CRAN version of `data.table`, 1.9.6.

Comment: @MichaelChirico you're right -- it didn't work in my example because I had reversed tab1 & tab2, so there was no such column in the table.

Comment: setup time is a little higher..?!? More than the typing time for every verb in dplyr? ;-P